# PHP script - echoing POSTed variables - Adding info to DB

Tags: php, variables, echo

**The php code on the web page calls out to a script in another file**
I can't even get it to echo out the variables I'm handing to it. I admit I'm pretty new to this, and am probably missing something obvious here.

```
                <p>
                <? if($_GET['e'] == "good"){ ?>
                    <h1><font color="#000000">Thank You! We will reply back as soon as possible.</font></h1><br /><br />
                <? } ?>

                <? if($_GET['e'] == "email"){ ?>
                    <h1><font color="#FF0000">Please check your input for bad email address or missing info!</font></h1><br /><br />
                <? } ?>

                <? if($_GET['e'] == "limit"){ ?>
                    <h1><font color="#FF0000">You have already been added!</font></h1><br />Feel Free to Call us @ !<br />
                <? } else { ?>
                    <h2>Input your info here:</h2>

                        <div style="height:20px"></div>
                        <form method="POST" action="doaction.php">
                        <table>
                            <tr><td width="60px">
                                <h3>Prefix:</h3></td><td width="260px">
                                <select name="prefix">
                                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                                <option value="Mr.">Mrs.</option>
                                <option value="Mr.">Ms.</option>
                                </select>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="60px">
                                <h3>First Name:</h3></td>   <td><input class="short_txt2" name="fname" type="text" />
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="60px">
                                <h3>Last Name:</h3></td>    <td><input class="short_txt2" name="lname" type="text" />
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                                <h3>E-mail:</h3></td>       <td><input class="short_txt2" name="email" type="text" />
                            </td></tr>
                        </table>

                        <div style="height:17px;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="do" value="addNLU">
                            <input class="submit2" name="send" type="submit" value="Join" />
                            <input class="submit2" name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
                        </div>

                        </form>
                <? } ?>
            </p>
```

**Here's the script it's supposed to run** (again. it won't even echo the variables on the first 4 lines...) (Now corrected to have the variables pulled from the POST - still nothing on the return script):

```
<?
session_start();
include "_funcs.php"; //This is where checkEmail is

$dothis = $_GET['do'];
if(empty($dothis)) $dothis=$_POST['do'];


if($dothis == "addNLU"){
$_SESSION['Newsletter'] = $_SESSION['Newsletter'] + 1;
$prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
$fname = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
$lname = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
$name = $prefix." ".$fname." ".$lname;
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$time = time();
echo $prefix;
echo $fname;
echo $lname;
echo $email;
exit;
$okemail = checkEmail($email);
if($okemail == 1){
    //if($_SESSION['Newsletter'] <= 2){  //INSTEAD OF THIS - CHECK THE DB TO SEE IF THEY'RE ALREADY THERE (NOT HOW MANY TIMES THEY HAVE SUBMITTED...)
        If !empty ($name) && !empty($email) {
            include "_db.connect.php";
            $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `zombiete`.`newsletter` (`prefix`, `lname`, `fname`, `email`, `when`) VALUES ('$prefix', '$lname', '$fname', '$email', '$time')")";
            mysql_close($db);
            $subject = "Newsletter user!";
            $body = "A new Newsletter User has been added: \n\n".$name."\n\nTake a Look!.\n\nhttp://www.us.us/workorder/newsletterlist.php";
            mail("neil@us.us", $subject, $body, "From: us.us");
            $subject = "Thanks for requesting our newsletter!";
            $body = "Hello ".$name."!\n\nYtour name and email address has been added to our database, and one of our newsletters should be arriving soon.\n\nThanks again, and be sure to let us know if there's anything we can do for you.";
            mail($email, $subject, $body, "From: name@us.us");
            header("Location: newsletter.php?e=good");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location: newsletter.php?e=email");
            exit;
        }
    //} else {
    //  header("Location: newsletter.php?e=limit");
    //}
} else {
    header("Location: newsletter.php?e=email");
}
}

?>
```

(Some info in the doaction script has been changed to protect certain variables from disclosure. Please disregard generic database name. email address to send to, I have those in there correctly.)

Comment: may b its because you are echo variables and exit before POST

Comment: I was missing 2 lines of code from the top of this file for the post and get statements. Also the <? and ?> are there in the main file of course. It's not THAT simple.. lol

Comment: Followed suggestion to switch variables and POST retrieval.. Still nogo.

Comment: Updated to show current code - still not working... it still won't do the basic echo. I'm reasonably certainif I can make that part work, the rest will flow on out. Please help if you can!!

Comment: I'm posting an answer, remove all of your code from your php file and replace with my code in my answer and see if you get echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope this helps

```
<?php session_start();
include "_funcs.php"; //This is where checkEmail is
include "_db.connect.php"; //This is database

//$dothis = $_GET['do']; Don't need this in my opinion
//if(empty($dothis)) $dothis=$_POST['do']; Don't need this in my opinion

if(isset($_POST['do']) && $_POST['do']=="addNLU"){
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $prefix = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prefix']);   
    $name = $prefix." ".$fname." ".$lname;
    echo $prefix;
    echo $fname;
    echo $lname;
    echo $email;

    $newsletter = $_SESSION['Newsletter'];

    //exit; // Why you wana exit here???
    $okemail = checkEmail($email);

    if(!empty($okemail)){
        //CHECK THE DB TO SEE IF THEY'RE ALREADY THERE (NOT HOW MANY TIMES THEY HAVE SUBMITTED...)
        //run your query here
        //set your conditions, header location, exit
        header("Location: newsletter.php?e=limit");
        exit();
    } else If (!empty ($name) && ($email)) {         
            $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `zombiete`.`newsletter` (`prefix`, `lname`, `fname`, `email`, `when`) VALUES ('$prefix', '$lname', '$fname', '$email', '$time')")";
            mysql_close($db);
            //Here you can put a check that above query run successful if you like before sending email 
            $subject = "Newsletter user!";
            $body = "A new Newsletter User has been added: \n\n".$name."\n\nTake a Look!.\n\nhttp://www.us.us/workorder/newsletterlist.php";
            mail("neil@us.us", $subject, $body, "From: us.us");

            $subject = "Thanks for requesting our newsletter!";
            $body = "Hello ".$name."!\n\nYtour name and email address has been added to our database, and one of our newsletters should be arriving soon.\n\nThanks again, and be sure to let us know if there's anything we can do for you.";
            mail($email, $subject, $body, "From: name@us.us");
            header("Location: newsletter.php?e=good");
            exit;
    } else {
        header("Location: newsletter.php?e=email");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No problem, lemme know if it works, if any problem, keep updating your question with the latest code and i will keep updating my answer according to it, will touch the finish line.

Answer (score 1):

The values are stored in the $_POST superglobal.

first name can be retrieved using

```
$_POST['fname']
```

but not only

```
$fname
```

unless you specifically assign a value to $fname

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
```

You need to do this BEFORE echoing $fname.

Comment: OK - I switched the code around, and put those lines first

 $fname = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
 $lname = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
 $name = $prefix." ".$fname." ".$lname;
 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $time = time();
 echo $prefix;
 echo $fname;
 echo $lname;
 echo $email;
 exit;

Comment: This was important and I've switched it, but still not working. Code has been modified in the original posting to show current coding.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `<?` to `<?php`. `<?` is wrong. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
//...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

`if($dothis == "addNLU")`

you should use,

`if($dothis == $_POST['addNLU']){`

Same goes for *prefix*, *fname* etc. 
As you are **POSTing** it from a form you should use `$_POST['fname']` to access them.

Also a syntax error here `If !empty ($name) && !empty($email)`. It should be `If (!empty ($name) && !empty($email))`.

Comment: The post and get statements were missing, I added them to the question above. Thanks for pointing out the syntax error!

Comment: More specifically, they were in the file, but all the way at the top. also just switched the POST and echo order

$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

    $time = time();

    echo $prefix;

Comment: Still not functional. I'd love to upvote this answer, but it says I need more feedback (15 or more) - But still not working.